# Can't install curses via pip3

Tags: python, macos, curses

I'm trying to install **curses** package for python 3.7. But got this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
```

Is this the problem with my version of python? Maybe some other similar package for python 3.7 exists?
My OS - MacOS 10.15.1

Comment: How did you try to install it? Give us your command. By the way, I don't see any [`curses` package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=curses) available for any Python version...

Comment: Curses usually refferes to (multiple) C implemented libraries, that are usually System installed or installable. There are also Python bindings to theses libraries, but they have different names.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? I’m also on macOS, and Conda has been a breeze so far.

Comment: if you mean [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses) then it is standard module and you should have it preinstalled with Python and you don't have to install it.

Comment: @furas I'm so stupid, thank you very much :))

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, thanks for the answer. My bad - this package is pre-installed in python.

Comment: @gurk My question still stands though ;p If it isn’t relevant now, it certainly will be eventually.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thank you :) I use PyCharm and it has his own venv system for every project. Should I consider using Conda anyway?

Comment: @gurk It’s up to you. Pycharm also has Conda integration, which is what I use. It would be difficult to write a full comparison here, so I’ll just provide a link to the docs. Bear in mind that Conda is **both** a package manager and an environment manager, which in your case means it would replace venv and at least partially replace pip. Docs: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/. This is a useful article on the sometimes confusing world of Anaconda and Conda: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2016/08/25/conda-myths-and-misconceptions/.

Answer (score -1):

I found somewhere that on Mac you need to use

```
pip install cursed
```

but I don't know if it's same package but looks fine for me.
Hope that's help

Comment: The commend section on the question discusses this: OP was trying to install a library that is already part of Python, so it does not need to be installed